# C# writing to binary file taking much longer than Delphi's

Tags: c#, delphi-7, filestream

I'm converting a Delphi app to C#. One part of the program requires writing many `packed records` in Delphi, or `structs` in C#, to a binary file. These files are around 400mb. The `Delphi` version I have completes writing to the file around `8 seconds`, whereas the `C#` version takes around `800 seconds`. What could I do to improve speed in the C# version?

Here's the Delphi version:

```
CONST
   RecordSize= 128;
   HeaderSize=128;

TESTrec = packed record
     now: TDateTime;
     //other fields here
     end;

TESThdrrec = packed record
    now: TDateTime;
    Firsttime: TDateTime;
    Lasttime: TDateTime;
    //other fields listed here
    end;

Function TRampBuildForm.CreateTest(FilePath:String;StartTime:TDateTime;EndTime:TDateTime):Boolean;
var
    Records:Int64;
    CurrentOffSet:Int64;
    CurrentTime:TDateTime;
    NewRec:TESTrec;
    NewHeader:TESThdrrec;
    ix:Integer;
    percent:Integer;

begin
    Try
      RampStream:=TFileStream.Create(FilePath,fmCreate OR fmShareExclusive );
    except
      ShowMessage('cannot create Ramp '+Rampname+chr(13)+'Check to see if file is open');
      CreateTest:=false;
    end;
    FillChar(NewHeader,HeaderSize,0);
    NewHeader.now:=Now;
    NewHeader.Firsttime:=StartTime;
    NewHeader.LastTime:= EndTime;
    FirstAllowableTime:=StartTime;
    LastAllowableTime:=EndTime;

    Records:= Round((EndTime-StartTime)/ONE_SECOND)+1;
    RampStream.Write(NewHeader,HeaderSize);

    FillChar(NewRec,RecordSize,0);
    label8.Caption:='Expanding ';
    Progressbar1.Position:=0;
    CurrentTime:=StartTime;
    percent:=0;
    refresh;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    For ix:= 1 to Records do
    begin
        if (ix*100) div Records > percent then
        begin
            percent:= (ix*100) div Records;
            Progressbar1.position:=percent;
            refresh;
            Application.ProcessMessages
        end;
        NewRec.Now:=CurrentTime;
        RampStream.Write(NewRec,RecordSize);
        CurrentTime:=CurrentTime + ONE_SECOND;
    end;
    ProgressBar1.Position:=100;
    refresh;

    CreateTest:=True;
    RampStream.Free;
end;
```

My C# version:

```
const int RecordSize = 128;
const int HeaderSize = 128;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Testrec
{
    public double now;
    //other fields here
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct TESThdrrec
{
    public double now;
    public double Firsttime;
    public double Lasttime;
    //other fields here
}

private Boolean CreateTest(string FilePath, double StartTime, double EndTime)
        {
            long Records;
            long CurrentOffSet;
            double CurrentTime;
            TESTrec NewRec = new TESTrec();
            TESThdrrec NewHeader = new TESThdrrec();
            int ix;
            int percent;

            NewHeader.now = System.DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
            NewHeader.Firsttime = StartTime;
            NewHeader.Lasttime = EndTime;
            FirstAllowableTime = StartTime;
            LastAllowableTime = EndTime;

            if (!File.Exists(FilePath)) //if file doesn't exist
            {
                try
                {
                    using (RampStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create)) 
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = GetBytes2(NewHeader); //puts struct into byte array
                        RampStream.Write(buffer, 0, HeaderSize); //write byte array to file
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Cannot create file" + RampName + Environment.NewLine + "Error Message: " + e);
                }
            }

            Records = (long)(Math.Round((EndTime - StartTime) / ONE_SECOND) + 1);

            RampInfo.Content = "Expanding ";
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0;
            CurrentTime = StartTime;
            percent = 0;

            //TAKING LONG TIME HERE!!
            for (ix = 1; ix <= Records; ix++)
            {
                if (((ix * 100) / Records) > percent)
                {
                    percent = (ix * 100) / (int)Records;
                }
                NewRec.now = CurrentTime;
                using (RampStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open)) 
                {
                    byte[] buffer = GetBytes2(NewRec); //puts struct into byte array
                    RampStream.Write(buffer, 0, RecordSize); //write byte array to file
                }
                //RampStream.Write(NewRec, RecordSize);
                CurrentTime = CurrentTime + ONE_SECOND;
            }

            ProgressBar1.Value = 100;

            RampStream.Close();
            return true;
        }
```

There is a progress bar being updated in the `for loop`, which is where the code is getting hung up on. I'm not refreshing it or using the `FillChar` equivalent that the Delphi version is using, but I don't think that would impact this?

Comment: You are opening and closing the stream for every write! Open the file once at the start of the writing loop, and close it at the end of the loop (like you do in the old code).

Comment: Yes! That fixed it, thank you for catching that. If you want to make it an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: You are, in my view, making a mistake by demanding that the program can only operate on disk files. If you would operate on a stream then you'd open up a lot of flexibility. Let the consumer of your code decide how to obtain the stream.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The files it will be reading/writing will be located where .exe is on the disk.

Comment: Then will come the day when somebody says, hey, let's save the file to a database instead, or a temporary memory stream. And then your decision to force it to disk will not look so clever. Steams are an abstraction to give you freedom and flexibility. Storing files next to the executable has long since been discredited, other than for portable applications.

Comment: I'll look into it, is it more complicated to do? IE, larger amount of code? All's I was told to do is strictly, line by line, convert from delphi to c#, but I'll mention this if it will save everyone a lot of trouble down the line.

Comment: You should read up on streams. Worth understanding the idea behind the abstraction. Even if your seniors don't want to know, you may as well learn. Might come in handy in the future if you move to a project with more freedom. It's not even remotely more complicated. If anything it would be simpler. The current code, both Delphi and C# versions, are utterly broken in their error handling. Failure to create the file leads to horrible runtime errors. The original author of the Delphi code was clueless. Verbatim translation, as you have been instructed to do, is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening and closing the stream for every write! Open the file once at the start of the writing loop, and close it at the end of the loop (like you do in the old code).

(You'll want to make sure you are still using a `using` statement to close the file.)

Comment: Marked as answer, but for some reason it's not writing the data now in the for loop? I have the `using` statement enclosing the `for loop`.

Comment: Nevermind! Seems to just be an issue with the test program I have that reads the files.

Comment: @pfinferno Where were you checking that the file has the data? The data will be buffered, and the buffer will only be written when the buffer is full - so some of the data may not be written until the file is closed.

Comment: After the operation completed and I closed down the app doing the writing. I tested it with a different app to read the data, and it all seemed to be there, so we're good! Thanks